# Accessing fields of a polymorphic descendant from a typesafe list

Tags: delphi

In Delphi 7, how do I design a descendant with polymorphism, so that the descendants can have a value field that is different from, or missing in the ancestor? I have a typesafe list that returns TMyObject like below.

But the Value field in the descendants below is not visible when I try to access it from the list. No surprise perhaps, since it doesn't exist in the base class, but how to handle this situation? I need to access the value of the descendant:

The typesafe list, containing TIntegerObjects and TSingleObjects:

```
List[Index].Value  <-- Doesn't exist!
```

List is typesafe and returns TMyObject items.

The TMyObject, and its descendants:

```
TMyObject = class
  procedure SaveToStream; virtual; abstract;
  procedure LoadFromStream; virtual; abstract;
end;

TIntegerObject = class(TMyObject)
  Value: Integer;
  procedure SaveToStream; override;
  procedure LoadFromStream; override;
end;

TSingleObject = class(TMyObject)
  Value: Single;
  procedure SaveToStream; override;
  procedure LoadFromStream; override;
end;
```

Comment: We don't know what `List` is. But you are going to need one list type for each member type. `TIntegerList`, `TSingleList` etc. Lots of boiler plate in Delphi 7. But it's an ancient compiler. You need a compiler with generics.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, why, you can test with if List[index] is TIntegerObject, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `is` operator to test if the object is of a certain class.

```
var
  obj: TMyObject;
  iValue: Integer;
  sValue: Single;
...
obj := List[index];
if obj is TIntegerObject then
  iValue := TIntegerObject(obj).Value // Access obj as TIntegerObject
else
if obj is TSingleObject then
  sValue := TSingleObject(obj).Value; // Access obj as TSingleObject
```

Comment: Question states that `List[index]` has type TMyObject so fewer casts are needed.

Comment: Yet TSingleObject is of TBaseObject which is confusing.

Comment: Oh yes. My guess is that there were renamings for Q. Real code uses none of these names.

Comment: Test with "is" and then casting works for me. Thanks very much! ps. TBaseObject was just a typo, it should read TMyObject. I'll edit the question.